# Visual Studio 2015: Command "View.SynchronizeClassView" is not available

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I added a Right-Click command to Synchronize the Class View, but it is always disabled.

I tried running the command in the Command Window, (Ctrl-Alt-A) and I get the error shown below:

```
>View.SynchronizeClassView
Command "View.SynchronizeClassView" is not available.
```

Any ideas what the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

> `DustinCampbell closed Implement View.SynchronizeClassView command #7073 in on Dec 1, 2015.`
>
> Unfortunately, VS 2015 Update 1 does not include this bug fix (it was released on November 21st). However, VS 2015 Update 2 RC was just released a few days ago and does include this.
>
> https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/7034#issuecomment-192703892